# Most efficient method of using PHP to read two files, math calculate, and write out result

Tags: php, performance, mathematical-optimization, file-writing

I have written a PHP script which opens two very large files (>1gb), both of which contain 4 columns. The script does a calculation on the corresponding values of each row in each file, and writes out the result to a third file.

My method is incredibly slow. I am using the `SplFileObject` to read the origin files and move the internal pointer line by line, as described in the code below.

It then writes out the result, line by line. However both the calculation and the write-out are very slow (the script is slow even if I disable the writes). I presume my method of file reading/writing are very inefficient and I'd appreciate tips for optimization.

```
function generate_adjusted($WGFile, $RFile) {

        // File Read objects
        $WGObj = new SplFileObject($WGFile);
        $RObj = new SplFileObject($RFile);

        // File write object
        $adjHandle = fopen("outputfile.txt", 'w+');

        foreach ($WGObj as $line) {
            // Line 0: ID1 (int), 1: ID2 (int), 2: NSNPs (int), 3: Relationship (real)
            $WGline = explode("\t", $WGObj->current());

            // Seek to the same line of second file
            $RObj->seek($WGObj->key());

            $Rline = explode("\t", $RObj->current());
            $A1 = floatval($WGline[2] * $WGline[3]);
            $A2 = floatval($Rline[2] * $Rline[3]);
            $ANSNP = $WGline[2] - $Rline[2];
            $A3 = round(floatval(($A1 - $A2) / $ANSNP), 3);

            // Construct the adjusted line
            $adjLine = $WGline[0] . "\t" . $WGline[1] . "\t" . $ANSNP . "\t" . $A3 . "\r\n";

            fwrite($adjHandle, $adjLine);
        }
        fclose($adjHandle);     
}

generate_adjusted('inputfile1.txt', 'inputfile2.txt');
```

Comment: What php version are you using? If I remember correctly spl related file functionality has some serious performance regressions in some versions.

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.3.10-1 on Ubuntu.

Comment: ->seek() is going to have read lines and scan for newlines, keeping a count as it goes. that's going to be inherently slow, especially if you're forcing rewinds/doing random access.

Comment: as @MarcB stated `seek` is going to be slow, since you are reading line by line you can simply remove that line.

Comment: The script is using `seek` on the second file to keep up with the pointer on the first file, since the calculations are done on the same relative line on each file. Is there a better method for extracting the line data from the second file?

Comment: Why has this been put on hold? Optimization for speed is not an *opinion*, it asks for methods that have measurable, quantitative improvements in execution time. Evidenced by an already-accepted answer which does exactly that.

Comment: "Most efficient" is going to be opinion. In the future, ask for "an efficient", not "most efficient".

Comment: @MarcusAdams One script implementation takes 1 second, another takes 5 seconds. Which is most efficient? That's not an opinion - it's a demonstrable outcome.

Comment: It's unlikely that the accepted answer is the most efficient way, (knowing that  writing your own extension in assembly language is possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and best advice: **benchmark it!**

Do not take any advice you get as a definitive fact (not even mine). Performance will vary based on your operating system, hardware and PHP version.

The following should be a fast approach and directly includes a micro-benchmark for you. Please test it and let us know.

```
<?php

$start = microtime(true);

function get_file_handle($file, $mode) {
    $h = fopen(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file, "{$mode}b");
    if (!$h) {
        trigger_error("Could not read {$file}.", E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    // Make sure nobody else is reading or writing to our file.
    if (flock($h, LOCK_SH | LOCK_EX) === false) {
        trigger_error("Could not acquire lock for {$file}", E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    return $h;
}

// We only want to read and not write.
$input_handle1 = get_file_handle("input1", "r");
$input_handle2 = get_file_handle("input2", "r");

// We only want to write and not read.
$output_handle = get_file_handle("output", "w");

// Read from both files at the same time the next line.
// NOTE: This only works if lines are always corresponding in both files.
while (($buffer1 = fgets($input_handle1)) !== false && ($buffer2 = fgets($input_handle2)) !== false) {
    $buffer1 = explode("\t", $buffer1);
    $buffer2 = explode("\t", $buffer2);

    // Forget floatval, let PHP do its dynamic casting.
    // NOTE: If precision is important use e.g. bcmath!
    $a1 = $buffer1[2] * $buffer1[3];
    $a2 = $buffer2[2] * $buffer2[3];
    $ansnp = $buffer1[2] - $buffer2[2];
    $a3 = round(($a1 - $a2) / $ansnp, 3);

    if (fwrite($output_handle, "{$buffer1[0]}\t{$buffer1[1]}\t{$ansnp}\t{$a3}\r\n") === false) {
        trigger_error("Could not write result to output file.", E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}

// Release locks on and close all file handles.
foreach (array($input_handle1, $input_handle2, $output_handle) as $delta => $handle) {
    if (flock($handle, LOCK_UN) === false) {
        trigger_error("Could not release lock!", E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    if (fclose($handle) === false) {
        trigger_error("Could not close file handle!", E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}

echo "Finished processing after " , (microtime(true) - $start) , PHP_EOL;
```

Of course this could be done in OO fashion as well with exceptions etc.

## Line Buffering

```
// Determines how many lines to buffer between each calculation/write.
$lines_to_buffer = 1000;

while (!feof($input_handle1) && !feof($input_handle2)) {
    $c1 = $c2 = 0;

    // Read lines from first handle, then read files from second handle.
    // NOTE: Reading multiple lines from the same file in a row allows us to make best use of the hard disk, if it isn't
    // an SSD, since we consecutively read from the same location which yields minimum seeks. But also keep in mind that
    // this might not be true if multiple processes are running in parallel, since they might read from different files
    // at the same time.
    foreach (array(1 => $input_handle1, 2 => $input_handle2) as $i => $handle) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            ${"buffer{$i}"}[] = explode("\t", $line);

            // Break if we read enough lines.
            if (++${"c{$i}"} === $lines_to_buffer) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Validate?
    if ($c1 !== $c2) {
        trigger_error("Lines from input files differ, aborting.", E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $lines_to_buffer; ++$i) {
        $a1 = $buffer1[$i][2] * $buffer1[$i][3];
        $a2 = $buffer2[$i][2] * $buffer2[$i][3];
        $ansnp = $buffer1[$i][2] - $buffer2[$i][2];
        $a3 = round(($a1 - $a2) / $ansnp, 3);
        $result .= "{$buffer1[0]}\t{$buffer1[1]}\t{$ansnp}\t{$a3}\r\n";
    }
    fwrite($output_handle, $result);

    // Reset
    $result = $buffer1 = $buffer2 = null;
}
```

Comment: This is a really excellent answer - thank you, and I appreciate your subsequent edits to make the method more specific to my problem! Does locking the file improve performance generally? In my application it's possible the input files would be read (but not written out) by more than one thread in parallel.

Additionally, would buffering the output before writing it improve performance? Maybe buffer 10-100k lines before doing a write?

Comment: No, locking should not have any significance in regards to performance, I mainly used them for security. You can safely remove them, but make sure you know what you are doing in regards to writing to the same file, I guess you can imagine why. ;) Depends on the typical line length you have. Buffering will greatly improve performance since most time is spend on seeking on the hard disk. You should also buffer the writes. How many lines depends on the amount of available memory.

Comment: You will have to try what works here, but I would start with a simple formula. `AMOUNT_OF_MEMORY / 4` for instance, now we have to estimate how many lines we can read so that it fits into one quarter of our memory and BAM there we go. We now know how many lines we can read from each input file and how many lines we can buffer before writing it to the output file. The last quarter is reserved for OS and PHP process.

Comment: Thank you - I can see how to buffer the writes - just appending to an output string until it's of a a certain size before writing it out, but you're also suggesting buffering the reads? Would that cause a problem when looping through the two buffers for both files? As if the read buffer for file 1 gets even one more line than file 2, it will create a mismatch? Many thanks.

Comment: I added an edited version which buffers 1,000 lines to the answer just to get you started. :)

Comment: I optimized the line buffering example and removed a severe bug, please check it out. Also consider going to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ with such questions in the future, you won't be down voted there. ;)